# Find an expression for $f(z)$ using Cauchy-Riemann Equations:

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with $f(z)=u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ is differentiable and that

$3u(x,y) + v(x,y) = 7$, $\forall z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$.

Find an expression for $f(z)$.

I've been told that I need to solve this using the Cauchy-Riemann equations(CRE) by finding a system of the partial derivatives from an expression like $f=u+i(7-3u)$. I understand how CRE work but can't work out how to find the solution in this case.

Comment: Given relation makes the function to be constant.

Comment: So I'd just write $f(z)= c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$??

Comment: Use CRE to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $f=u+i(7-3u)$ we get by the CRE:

$u_x=-3u_y$ and $u_y=3u_x.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: That's exactly what I have written down, though I wasn't sure that it was correct, but I have no idea where to go from there!

Comment: My equations give $ u_x=u_y=0.$

Comment: Okay thanks I can see that. But how does that them help me in finding an expression for $f(z)$?

Comment: If the partial derivatives are known you can integrate to find the functions. Take care, though with the constant functions...